# Find processes causing the fans running

Tags: command-line, hardware, temperature, fan

During years, I have found it very difficult to have control over my laptop fan. I tried many times reading various manuals, scripts, settings and nothing worked.

So I would like to try it another way. I noticed that one of the factors influencing the fans running is how many and which type of applications are running.

Could you find (command line) the processes that are causing higher temperatures and running the fans?
From that list of processes, I would terminate those which I don't need much to be running.

Comment: You can use the `top` command to see which processes are using the CPU intensively (which in turn cause the fans to run)

Comment: Or you can use the `powertop` command to `diagnose various issues with power consumption and power management` (from the manpage). The interactive mode has a "Usage" column that tels you how much time per second is being used by processes, timers, interrupts, etc.

Comment: Thanks, there seems I have to figure out what to turn off.